# Why are my margins changing on second page using itextsharp?

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp to create pdfs. However, for some reason that I can't fathom, when the text goes onto the second page, it jumps down a line. I'm not adding a Chunk.NEWLINE anywhere, so I can only assume the document margin changes. This change only happens from page 1-2; it then remains constant for the rest of the document.

I noticed it when I created a method to add a header to the page, which overwrites OnEndPage; nevertheless, the effect happens when I don't call the method, and don't change OnEndPage at all, or the margins. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here is the code I use to create my pdf:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using it = iTextSharp.text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using Helper;

namespace Andrew
{
    public class AndrewFunctions
    {
        public void createPDF()
        {
            //Create new document
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        //Create instance= of pdfwriter named test to write to file
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Gabriela\Desktop\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        try
        {
            //Add primary info to pdf and open for editing  
            doc.AddTitle("My first pdf");
            doc.AddCreator("Andrew Birch");                

            //Set font and color
            it.Font myfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Garamond");
            myfont.SetColor(51, 51, 255);

            doc.Open();

            //Add filler content to pdf
            for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
            {
                doc.Add(new Phrase("This is filler text", myfont));
            }  

            //Create header table
            PdfPTable testTable = new PdfPTable(3);
            testTable.WidthPercentage = 100f; 
            float[] widths = { 1f, 3f, 1f };
            testTable.SetWidths(widths);

            //Header table images
            string path = "C:\\Users\\Gabriela\\Desktop\\descarga.png";
            it.Image logo = doc.ImportarImagen(path, 24f);
            path = "C:\\Users\\Gabriela\\Desktop\\descarga2.png";
            it.Image logo2 = doc.ImportarImagen(path, 24f, AlineacionCelda.CentradoVCentradoH);

            //Fill header table
            doc.CrearCeldaImagen(logo, testTable, false, it.Color.BLUE, AlineacionCelda.CentradoVCentradoH, rowspan: 4);
            doc.CrearCelda("TEST TABLE HEADER", testTable, font, it.Color.BLUE, AlineacionCelda.Centro, BordeCelda.SinBorde);
            doc.CrearCeldaImagen(logo2, testTable, false, it.Color.BLUE, AlineacionCelda.CentradoVCentradoH, rowspan: 4);
            doc.CrearCelda("HEADER LINE TWO WITH A WICKED SUBTITLE", testTable, font, it.Color.BLUE, AlineacionCelda.Centro, BordeCelda.SinBorde);
            doc.CrearCelda("HEADER LINE THREE", testTable, font, it.Color.BLUE, AlineacionCelda.Centro, BordeCelda.SinBorde);
            doc.CrearCelda("YOU GUESSED IT, HEADER LINE 4", testTable, font, it.Color.BLUE, AlineacionCelda.Centro, BordeCelda.SinBorde);

            //Add heading before opening doc
            doc.AgregarCabezado(testTable, writer, doc);

        }
        catch (it.DocumentException dex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dex.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ioex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close doc and writing stream
            doc.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

The difference is more easily appreciated with the header, some screenshots to show what I mean:

[Without Header, page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Vp1.png)

[Without Header, page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqyWJ.png)

With Header, page 1:   i.stack.imgur.com/m8rmm.png

With Header, page 2:   i.stack.imgur.com/VV8a7.png

The namespace Helper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using it = iTextSharp.text;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;

namespace Helper
{
    //Alignment values
    public enum AlineacionCelda : byte
    {
        Izquierda = 1,
        Centro,
        Derecha,
        AbajoIzquierda,
        CentradoVCentradoH,
        Justificado
    }
    //Border values
    public enum BordeCelda : byte
    {
        SinBorde,
        Arriba,
        Abajo,
        ArribaAbajo,
        Izquierda,
        IzquierdoArriba,
        IzquierdoAbajo,
        IzquierdoArribaAbajo,
        Derecha,
        DerechaArriba,
        DerechaAbajo,
        DerechaArribaAbajo,
        DerechaIzquierda,
        DerechaIzquierdaArriba,
        DerechaIzquierdaAbajo,
        Todos
    }

    public class Pdf : it.Document
    {
        //Default variables
        public static it.Font fuenteDefaultStatic = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11, it.Font.NORMAL, it.Color.BLACK);
        public it.Font fuenteDefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11, it.Font.NORMAL, it.Color.BLACK);
        public it.Font fuentePartidaDefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, it.Font.NORMAL, it.Color.BLACK);
        public it.Font fuentePartidaNegritaDefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK);
        public it.Font fuenteNegritaDefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11, it.Font.BOLD, it.Color.BLACK);
        public it.Color fondoDefault = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE;

        public Pdf() : base() { }
        public Pdf(it.Rectangle pageSize): base(pageSize) {}
        public Pdf(it.Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom) : base(pageSize, marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom) { }

        //Create a cell in the table specified with the attributes specified: use default values if any are omitted.  
        public void CrearCelda(string valor, PdfPTable tabla, iTextSharp.text.Font fuente = default(it.Font), it.Color fondo = default(it.Color), AlineacionCelda alineacion = AlineacionCelda.Izquierda, BordeCelda borde = BordeCelda.Todos,
        int colspan = 1, int rowspan = 1)
        {
            try
            {

                if (fuente == default(it.Font))
                {
                    fuente = fuenteDefault;
                }

                PdfPCell celda = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(valor, fuente));
                if (fondo == default(it.Color))
                {
                    fondo = fondoDefault;
                }

                celda.BackgroundColor = fondo;

                switch (borde) //Check and set border accordingly
                {
                    case BordeCelda.SinBorde: celda.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Arriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Abajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.ArribaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Izquierda: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.IzquierdoArriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.IzquierdoAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.IzquierdoArribaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Derecha: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaArriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaArribaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierda: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierdaArriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierdaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Todos: celda.Border = PdfPCell.BOX; break;
                }

                if (colspan != 1)
                {
                    celda.Colspan = colspan;
                }
                else
                {
                    celda.Colspan = 1;
                }
                if (rowspan != 1)
                {
                  celda.Rowspan = rowspan;
                }
                else
                {
                    celda.Rowspan = 1;
                }

                switch (alineacion) //Check and set alignment accordingly
                {
                    case AlineacionCelda.Izquierda: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.Centro: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.Derecha: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.AbajoIzquierda: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; celda.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.CentradoVCentradoH: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; celda.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.Justificado: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED; break;
                 }
                tabla.AddCell(celda);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
         }

        //Creates cell containing the image specified in the table specified
        public void CrearCeldaImagen(it.Image imagen, PdfPTable tabla, bool autoFit = false, it.Color fondo = default(it.Color), AlineacionCelda alineacion = AlineacionCelda.Izquierda, BordeCelda borde = BordeCelda.SinBorde,
        int colspan = 1, int rowspan = 1)
        {
            try
            {

                PdfPCell celda = new PdfPCell(imagen, autoFit);
                if (fondo != default(it.Color))
                {
                    celda.BackgroundColor = fondo;
                }

                switch (alineacion) //Checks and sets the alignment accordingly
                {
                    case AlineacionCelda.Izquierda: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.Centro: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.Derecha: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.AbajoIzquierda: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; celda.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM; break;
                    case AlineacionCelda.CentradoVCentradoH: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; celda.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE; break;
                    default: celda.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; break;
                }

                switch (borde) //Checks and sets the border accordingly
                {
                    case BordeCelda.SinBorde: celda.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Arriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Abajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.ArribaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Izquierda: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.IzquierdoArriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.IzquierdoAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.IzquierdoArribaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Derecha: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaArriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaArribaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierda: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierdaArriba: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.TOP_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierdaAbajo: celda.Border = PdfPCell.RIGHT_BORDER | PdfPCell.LEFT_BORDER | PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                    case BordeCelda.Todos: celda.Border = PdfPCell.BOX; break;
                    default: celda.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER; break; 
                }

                if (colspan != 1)
                    celda.Colspan = colspan;
                else
                {
                    celda.Colspan = 1;
                }
                if (rowspan != 1)
                    celda.Rowspan = rowspan;
                else
                    celda.Rowspan = 1;

                tabla.AddCell(celda);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        //Returns the image at the specified path, using the scale percentage, alignment, and border specified
        public it.Image ImportarImagen(string rutaImagen, float escalaPorcentaje = 100f, AlineacionCelda alineacion = AlineacionCelda.Izquierda, BordeCelda borde = BordeCelda.SinBorde)
        {
            it.Image imagen = it.Image.GetInstance(rutaImagen);
            imagen.ScalePercent(escalaPorcentaje);
            switch (alineacion) //Check and set alignment
            {
                case AlineacionCelda.Izquierda: imagen.Alignment = it.Image.ALIGN_LEFT; break;
                case AlineacionCelda.Centro: imagen.Alignment = it.Image.ALIGN_CENTER; break;
                case AlineacionCelda.Derecha: imagen.Alignment = it.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT; break;
                case AlineacionCelda.CentradoVCentradoH: imagen.Alignment = it.Image.ALIGN_CENTER | it.Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE; break;
                default: imagen.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; break;
            }

            switch (borde) //Check and set border
            {
                case BordeCelda.SinBorde: imagen.Border = it.Image.NO_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.Arriba: imagen.Border = it.Image.TOP_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.Abajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.ArribaAbajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.TOP_BORDER | it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.Izquierda: imagen.Border = it.Image.LEFT_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.IzquierdoArriba: imagen.Border = it.Image.LEFT_BORDER | it.Image.TOP_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.IzquierdoAbajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.LEFT_BORDER | it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.IzquierdoArribaAbajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.LEFT_BORDER | it.Image.TOP_BORDER | it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.Derecha: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.DerechaArriba: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER | it.Image.TOP_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.DerechaAbajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER | it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.DerechaArribaAbajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER | it.Image.TOP_BORDER | it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierda: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER | it.Image.LEFT_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierdaArriba: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER | it.Image.LEFT_BORDER | it.Image.TOP_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.DerechaIzquierdaAbajo: imagen.Border = it.Image.RIGHT_BORDER | it.Image.LEFT_BORDER | it.Image.BOTTOM_BORDER; break;
                case BordeCelda.Todos: imagen.Border = it.Image.BOX; break;
                default: imagen.Border = it.Image.NO_BORDER; break;
            }
            if (imagen.Border != it.Image.NO_BORDER)
            {
                imagen.BorderWidth = 1f;
            }
            return imagen;
        }

        public void agregarCabezado(PdfPTable tabla, PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            //Change margins to adapt to the Header
            document.SetMargins(document.LeftMargin, document.RightMargin, document.TopMargin + tabla.TotalHeight + 50f, document.BottomMargin);            
            Cabezado cabezado = new Cabezado(tabla);
            writer.PageEvent = cabezado;
        }

        public class Cabezado : PdfPageEventHelper
        {
            //Table used for the header
            public PdfPTable tablaCabezado { get; set; }

            public Cabezado(PdfPTable tabla)
            {
                this.tablaCabezado = tabla;
            }

            // Place the header on each page 
            public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
            {
                 try
                 {
                      base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

                      //To ensure WriteSelectedRows respects the Rowspan
                      ArrayList tmp = tablaCabezado.GetRows(0, tablaCabezado.Size);
                      tablaCabezado.Rows.Clear();
                      tablaCabezado.Rows.AddRange(tmp);

                      //Calculate the positioning of the header
                      float posicionY = document.PageSize.Height - tablaCabezado.TotalHeight;
                      tablaCabezado.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, posicionY, writer.DirectContent);
                 }
                 catch (DocumentException ex)
                 {
                     throw ex;
                 }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Without the header the pages are pixels perfect top aligned to me. Your header version includes a table so I don't know how to invoke it, but this line is suspicious: `document.SetMargins(document.LeftMargin, document.RightMargin, document.TopMargin + tabla.TotalHeight + 50f, document.BottomMargin);`

Comment: I agree with @ChrisHaas. Also: you have a method called `agregarCabezado()`, but it is unclear if you ever use that method. Your code is probably as sloppy as your question. Clean up your code, and if that still doesn't solve your problem: clean up your question.

Comment: Thanks for the polite response!

The method is only invoked to create the heading (agregarCabezado) is add heading in Spanish, which is why it isn't used in the first section of code. 

Likewise I thought it might be an illusion, that is, until I added the header and the difference became abundantly clear. The header is positioned absolutely, with the idea being that the margins are adjusted to the size of the header.

Comment: The table is created using a method that sets the attributes of each cell. The question remains though, why, if I'm calling SetMargins before opening the document, and adding the header with OnEndPage (and not changing the margins afterwards), why would the margins change as per the screenshots?

Comment: I have completely revamped the question, making the focus clearer, and added the complete update code. I have also changed the colors in the screenshots to make what I mean more visible.

Comment: @PatoPan At first glance: You declare `Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4)`, i.e. doc is an iTextSharp `Document`, but then you call methods like `doc.CrearCeldaImagen` which definitely are not in the iTextSharp `Document` but instead in your `Pdf` class. Furthermore you reference an `iTextSharp.text.Color` but iTextSharp only has a `BaseColor` class there. Could it be something got mixed up while copying&pasting?

Comment: That been said, your example code is too long, even your updated code. Please boil it down to only contain relevant code.